# UPLOAD - SEM ACESSO À ARQUIVOS

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Montei um servidor web com apache 2.4 e php em casa. Criei um script de upload de arquivos e deu tudo certinho, a não ser que ao fazer o upload quando vou visualizar as fotos baixadas na pasta do servidor ele me diz que eu não tenho acesso e não permite visualizar. Alguém tem alguma dica do que pode tá acontecendo ? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que alterar as permissões da pasta onde está armazenando as imagens!

Se está usando Linux, eu já não sei o procedimento em modo gráfico, pois há uns meses que não uso!

Se usa Windows, basta ir na pasta onde estão armazenadas as imagens, e clicar com o botão `Direito`, e ir em `Propriedades`, depois na aba `Segurança` clicando em `Editar...` selecione um usuário, e prossiga editando as permissões!

Se estiver usando Linux, tente mudar as permissões via comando, no caso pesquise por CHMOD!

Comment: De que forma... ?

Comment: Editandoooooo..

Comment: obrigado por tentar me ajudar !! Eu uso Windows 7 e já tentei alterar as configurações de pastas como você falou, só que ao fazer isso reparei que já esta tudo liberado na minha pasta de servidor, não tem o que fazer.

Comment: @SampaioLeal eu achei que tinha um modo de fazer direto no php...

Comment: @MagicHat cara, slá, eu pensei que ele estivesse com problemas para acessar a imagem através do navegador, mas não passou pela minha cabeça que o problema era no pc dele né